# Undefined '_this2.props.navigation.navigate'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have problems, i want to navigate to register from login in Modal. how solved this problem?

how so I can navigate in the Modal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMZgm.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6Gn.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Dimensions, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import Lock from '../../../assets/icon/lock.svg';
import User from '../../../assets/icon/user.svg';

var screen = Dimensions.get('window');
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    showLogin = () => {
        this.refs.myLogin.open();
    }

    closeLogin = () => {
        this.refs.myLogin.close();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                ref={"myLogin"}
                style={{
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    width: screen.width - 80,
                    shadowRadius: 10,
                    height: 300,
                }}
                position='center'
                backdrop={true}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

and this button

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
    <Text style={{ color: '#024379', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Daftar Disini</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Create navigation service then import where you want and use it

Comment: Look at documentation too => https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `withNavigation` HOC to be able to access navigation prop in your component.

For reference see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav)